# How to check whether date is in past or not in moment js?

Tags: javascript, date, conditional-statements, momentjs

After going through lots of links, I could not find a condition that satisfy past date.

It should include `today` date as well.

```
todays_date = 2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z
```

Something like this:

```
moment(2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z).isBefore();
```

How can I write a condition that includes today's date, past date and return true/false.

Comment: `moment().startOf('day').isSameOrBefore('2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z')`

Comment: or even -> `moment().isSameOrBefore('2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z', 'day')`    https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar the other day for a project.
I just compared `moment()` to the past date.

```
var isBefore = moment() > moment(pastDate);
```

Or as you want a function

```
function isBefore(pastDate){
   return moment() > moment(pastDate);
}
```

`moment()` returns the current date and dont forget to pass a string in for the `pastDate`: "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"

Ex:

```
moment() > moment("2020-02-17T00:00:00.000Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const dateFormat = 'D MMM'
const isPast = date => moment(date, dateFormat).isBefore(moment(), 'day')
```

you can change the format date